# Simple pagination not working in Android

Tags: java, android, pagination

I have a list view that implement a basic paging algorithm like this :

```
page + 1 everytime user click "load more", and page start from 0

offset = page * limit;

limit has final static value
```

This is the query :

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM  OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10
```

It should be easy & simple, but it returns the wrong result. The items always be duplicated, so the query is selecting the same item instead of the next item.

This is the log cat :

```
First page : offset 0 page 0 limit 11

First page : offset 11 page 1 limit 11

First page : offset 22 page 2 limit 11
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So page 1 is correct, but page 2 and 3 (etc.) are just duplicates of page 1?

Comment: Consider adding some relevant code involving your adapter.